# Div background color isn't filling 100% of the height of the text when reducing the window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a `<div>` that has a grey background color, with another <`div`> inside of that which contains text.

When I shrink the window size, the background isn't 100% height anymore, and I want for the background color to fill the background of all the text.

This is my code:

```css
#info-workshop {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 1565px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.containertext {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  #info-workshop {
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="info-workshop">
  <div class="containertext">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text
      copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random
      text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text
      copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random
      text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over again

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made a 'media' tag to try to make should make the background color 100% when the window width is below 767 pixels, but it doesn't seem to work.

What do I need to do to make the background 100% of the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the height on the container div:

```
#info-workshop {
    [...]
    height: 1565px;
    [...]
}
```

The text is showing outside this because it is "overflowing" its parent, but the background will only fill the actual height of the parent - it won't fill the overflow.

You need to remove the height! You can remove the following too, as it won't help:

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    #info-workshop {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Lastly, you also forgot to include the `row` class on the parent of the `col`s, i.e.

```
<div class="containertext row">
```

**Working Snippet:**

```css
#info-workshop {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.containertext {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="info-workshop">
  <div class="containertext row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text
      copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random
      text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text
      copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again
      Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random
      text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over again Just some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted over and over againJust some random text copy and pasted
      over and over again

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```